# phpcoding special characters

Tags: javascript, php

When I load a php page, i put within a javascript function, a name. The problem comes when this string has special chars like '.

Here I paste the code of a click event:

```
showSocialShare(event, '<?php echo $object->slug; ?>', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($object->title); ?>', '<?php echo $object->image; ?>')
```

I thought that the function **htmlspecialchars** code somehow the string but the result is:

```
showSocialShare(event, '4049269', 'collection-'Noun'', '/img/Original.jpg')
```

As can be seen, at the second parameter, the name contains characters like ' and arises an error.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: The output will be a javascript function?

Comment: yes, it's inserted in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Never output text from PHP directly into a Javascript context. As you're finding out, it's **VERY** easy to generate JS syntax errors.

Always use json_encode: e.g. given this

```
<?php    $foo = 'bar';    ?>

<script>
   var badly_broken = <?php echo $foo ?>;
   var working_fine = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;
</script>
```

You'll end up with

```
<script>
    var badly_broken = bar;   // oops - undefined variable "bar"
    var working_fine = "bar";
</script>
```

And note that if you're outputting JS into an HTML attribute, you not only have to generate valid Javascript, you have to output valid HTML **AS WELL**:

```
<?php $foo = array('bar' => 'baz'); ?>

<a onclick="brokenCall(<?echo json_encode($foo) ?>)">
<a onclick="workinCall(<? echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($foo)) ?>)">
```

produces:

```
<a onclick="brokenCall({"bar":"baz"})">
           ^--start attribute
                        ^--end attribute - ruhroh

<a onclick="workingCall({&quot;bar&quot;:&quot;baz&quot;}")>
```

Comment: I have used htmlspecialchars(json_encode($my_string)) and keep ' characters.